# Nested unordered lists from nested array (recursive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a bit of code that loops through nested array (it can be unlimited in depth) and I am trying to generate a treelike structure from it.. of basically nested unordered lists..

**Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aj9TC/6/**

I collect items names in a function like this:

```
function get_list( a ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         console.log( i + "---" + a[i].name );

         $(".mod-list ul").append('<li>' + a[i].name + '</li>');

         get_list( a[i].group );
     }
}

get_list( mods.group );
```

My sample html is simple

```
<h4>Nested List</h4>
<div class="mod-list">

    <ul class="list">

    </ul>

</div>
```

I currently append all items as li in a single unordered list,, but I need to create nested unordered lists that reflect the array nesting accurately.

Can someone help me out with this please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution that doesn't leave empty `<ul>`'s
I also like to build up all my html and add it to the DOM once, instead of adding lots of little snippets.

```
function get_list( a, str ) {
    str += '<ul>';
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        str += '<li>' + a[i].name;
        if (a[i].group && a[i].group.length) str += get_list( a[i].group, '' );
        str += '</li>';
    }
    str += '</ul>';
    return str;
}

$(".mod-list").append(get_list( mods.group, ''));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aj9TC/8/

Comment: Thank you so very much. I find all three posted solutions useful but this one is the most practical for my actual use case. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
function get_list( a, $parent ) {
    var newUl = $("<ul></ul>");
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i]) {
            newUl.append('<li>' + a[i].name + '</li>');
            if (a[i].group)
                get_list( a[i].group, newUl );
        }

    }
    $parent.append(newUl);
}

get_list( mods.group, $(".mod-list"));
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aj9TC/7/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that also builds all the html in array of strings and only does one append when done. Join array when ready to insert.

```
$(function(){
    var $list=$(get_list(mods.group,[]).join('')).addClass('list')
     $('.mod-list').append($list) 
});

function get_list(data, strArray) {
    strArray.push('<ul>');
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        strArray.push('<li>' + val.name);
        if (val.group) {
            get_list(val.group,strArray);
        }
        strArray.push('</li>');
    });
    strArray.push('</ul>');
    return strArray;
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nZJ35/2/)**</kbd>